# What are the differences between security levels?

Tags: security, tor-browser-bundle

Tor browser has different security levels. What are these and what are the main differences between them?

Answer (score 2):

If you hover over the names of the various security levels on the Privacy and Security Settings it should provide a brief synopsis of the various things that they each do.

For a more detailed view you can look at the settings it is toggling in the [torbutton code base](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbutton.git/tree/src/chrome/content/torbutton.js#n2301), and for some of the reasoning behind the choices see the [ticket it was created under](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9387).